# jquery append refusing to assign value to select

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

so i have an mvc project using php/js/oracle db on the backend and this one thing is completely stumping me.
i have a select that im trying to fill with and array of values received from an ajax call. but when i try to append.() the values to the select nothing happens, no errors that i can see, nothing. it just doesnt assign the values like how i think it should work. this is the block of code

```
`$("#newuserModal #bscid").focusout(function () {
    var based_url = $('#base_url').text();
    var bscidlong = $('#newuserModal #bscid').val();



    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: based_url + '/user_data/get_roles',
        data: {bsc_id: bscidlong},
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
    var prole = JSON.parse(data);
        var $option = $("<option>");
        $option.val("");
        $option.text("Select a location type.");
        $select.append($option);

            if (prole != undefined && prole.length > 0) {
                prole.map(function (d, i) {
                    $('#newuserModal #f_process_role').append(new Option(d.p_role, d.p_role_id));
                })
            }

        }
    })
});`
```

stepping through as the focusout executes the ajax is fine, i get the array of data i expect, hits the if statement loops through without issue but when it gets to the append literally nothing happens and the event ends and the values are not assigned, front end dev really isnt my thing so im stumped as to what is wrong.

Comment: Can you post the modal HTML so one can see what it looks like?

Comment: @chyke007 sure i edited to include it

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a typo which is causing the issue:

```
<select class="form-control col-md-7" id="f_process_role" name="f_process_role" style=" height: 32px;">
```

the id is "**f_process_role**" while in your js code you are checking for an id of  **#f_p_role**

```
 $('#newuserModal #f_p_role').append(new Option(d.p_role, d.p_role_id));
```

You can choose to update the select to match your id as thus:

```
<select class="form-control col-md-7" id="f_p_role" name="f_p_role" style=" height: 32px;">
```

Comment: oof thats a mistake on my part copying it over, copied from the wrong location the ids do match within the code ill edit to update though

Comment: sorry about the bad copy, doing this one handed had surgery on my right hand the other day

Comment: Sorry to hear about that, would review as soon as possible